# Expand a power of the difference operator in terms of time series $z_t$

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, arma

I am trying to use excel to plot different time series. I have the equation

$(1-L)^2 * z_t$

I know that $(1-L)*z_t$ is equal to $z_t-z_{t-1}$

Can I just expand $(1-L)^2$ using basic algebra and get a function in terms of just the $z_t$'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you gave yourself is incorrect - sorry you had to wait for an answer! $(1-L)^2 = 1-2L+L^2$, and so $(1-L)^2z_t = z_t - 2z_{t-1} + z_{t-2}$, since $L^2z_t = Lz_{t-1} = z_{t-2}$.

There is another way to see this: $\Delta := (1-L)$, so $(1-L)^2 = \Delta^2$. The intuitive $\Delta$ just denotes the first difference (i.e., $\Delta z_t = z_t - z_{t-1}$), so $\Delta^2z_t = \Delta (z_t - z_{t-1}) = (z_t - z_{t-1}) - (z_{t-1} - z_{t-2}) = z_t - 2z_{t-1} + z_{t-2}$

Answer (score 0):

Just use the general notation:

$(1−L)(1−L^m)z_t=(1−L−L^m+L^{m+1})z_t=z_t−z_{t−1}−z_{t−m}+z_{t−m−1}$

to get your desired answer as:

$(1-L)^2 = z_t-2*z_{t-1} + z_t$]

FYI I answered my own question because no one felt like lending a helping hand.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your second equation: I have a feeling you meant to put "t-2" where you have written "t]"?